# Ionic 5 declared modules give error on app.module.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

i am using Ionic 5 for my project i try to put modules i used in my ionic 3 project like Camera and i am getting redlighted error.

Camera, StreamingMedia,MediaCapture,Media,File,FileChooser are redlighted

the problem is that when i delete import { Transfer } from '@ionic-native/transfer'; the errors are gone but when i put it back on the errors are appearing again. Whats u with Transfer?

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { AppData } from './services/app-data/app-data';
import { UserData } from './services/user-data/user-data';
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MediaCapture } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';
import { Media } from '@ionic-native/media';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Transfer } from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import { StreamingMedia } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { UserProfileModalPageModule } from './pages/user-profile-modal/user-profile-modal.module';
import { UserProfilePopoverComponent } from './components/user-profile-popover/user-profile-popover.component';

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, UserProfilePopoverComponent],
   entryComponents: [UserProfilePopoverComponent],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     IonicModule.forRoot(),
     AppRoutingModule,
     LazyLoadImageModule,
     IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
     HttpClientModule,
     AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
     AngularFireAuthModule,
     FormsModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     AngularFirestoreModule,
     UserProfileModalPageModule
    ],
    providers: [
     StatusBar,
     AppData,
     UserData,
     SplashScreen,
     **Camera,**
     { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
     **StreamingMedia,**
     Transfer,
     **MediaCapture,**
     **Media,**
     **File,**
     **FileChooser**
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
```

Does it have to do with the order i am calling them?
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you're using the wrong imports. please use for ionic5 the following imports:

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media/ngx';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser/ngx';
```

Comment: This is correct. Ionic documentation is really sparse regarding this but the ngx folder seems to be a convention for exporting angular friendly apis

Comment: i have installed this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/camera and i put import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx'; but nothing happens

Comment: the problem is that when i delete import { Transfer } from '@ionic-native/transfer'; the errors are gone but when i put it back on the errors are appearing again. Whats u with Transfer?

Comment: @SimonIoa Transfer moved to FileTransfer (please read the doc here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer)

Comment: yes i did that. when i put original the errors are gone. CameraOriginal,
    StreamingMediaOriginal,
    FileTransferOriginal,
    MediaCaptureOriginal,
    MediaOriginal,
    FileOriginal,
    FileChooserOriginal,

Comment: is that the proper thing to do?

Comment: i would recommend to use it without the "Original" as described in the documentation.